# Python objects bound method

Tags: python

I made this stacks program:

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        return self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def Items(self):
        print self.items
```

When I try `stack.empty` it says `<bound method Stack.empty of <__main__.Stack object at 0x01C437B0>>`. I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that is to check if the stack is empty. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Note that your `Stack.push()` method will always return `None`. That's ok, but it would be more usual to write it without a `return` statement.

Answer (score 5):

You simply forgot *call* the method:

```
stack.empty()
```

If you must have it work as an attribute, use a [`property` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
@property
def empty(self):
    return self.items == []
```

You could just use `not` here, empty containers are considered false in a boolean context, `not self.items` produces `True` if the container is empty:

```
@property
def empty(self):
    return not self.items
```

Demo (without a `property` to demonstrate the method):

```
>>> class Stack(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.items = []
...     def empty(self):
...         return not self.items
...     def push(self, item):
...         return self.items.append(item)
...     def pop(self):
...         return self.items.pop()
... 
>>> stack = Stack()
>>> stack.empty
<bound method Stack.empty of <__main__.Stack object at 0x10211c090>>
>>> stack.empty()
True
>>> stack.push('foo')
>>> stack.empty()
False
>>> stack.pop()
'foo'
>>> stack.empty()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

While defining `empty` as method you need to call it with `()` or `.__call__()`, otherwise you can use python's neat "property" feature, just modify your code like this:

```
@property
def empty(self):
    return self.items == []
```

then you can access this method as attribute `self.empty`

For more information go to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property